# Single sign-on for Spring MVC and Dropwizard microservice

Tags: java, spring-mvc, single-sign-on, dropwizard

I have two applications: Spring MVC one and Dropwizard microservice. They communicate through Kafka. I have configured simple Spring security in MVC and have no security in microservice yet.
I need to implement SSO, so when I sign in on one application, I don't need to do it again on another.
My plan is to use LDAP. Maybe you'll recomend smth better? 
Any advices on how to start, helpful links?

Thanks!

Comment: SSO is mainly for cross domain issue, are those two apps under diff domains?

Comment: yeah, they are.

Comment: by nature, the webapp is quite different from microservice due to the audience. I will just use AWS as example, like AWS gateway will sit in front of AWS Lambda (microservice), gateway will handle the authentication/authorization. While SSO mainly get used for a bunch of webapps under different domains. Let me know if it makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at Keycloak.  Users authenticate with Keycloak, which can use LDAP as a back end.  Keycloak generates signed authentication tokens which the user forwards on each request.  Each service can independently verify the token.